# Prevent to Cache Login Information

Tags: caching, typo3

I'am using **femanager** to manage user registration, login and logout.

Like many other websites, I'd like to show some user information on the top of the page (using Boostraps *mini-navbar*).

- If the user is logged out, this should look like:
  [image: Call for registration if the user is not logged in]
- If the user is logged in, this information should displayed:
  [image: Greetings if the user is logged in]

As a Typo3 beginner, I implement this with Typo Script and a partial in Fluid Template. The Typo Script reads the current user (user id and e-mail address).

```
userdata = COA_INT
userdata {
  10 = TEXT
  10.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|uid
  20 = TEXT
  20.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|username
}
```

The partial uses the user id to check if the user is logged in or logged out.

```
<f:if condition="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'userdata.10')} > 0">
  <f:then>
      <!-- user is logged in -->
      <span class="greeting">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="userdata.20" />
      </span>
      <f:link.page pageUid="319" additionalParams="{logintype: 'logout'}" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout</f:link.page>
  </f:then>
  <f:else>
     <!-- user is logged out -->
      <span class="greeting">
        Test it for free
      </span>
      <f:link.page pageUid="317" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i> Register</f:link.page>
      <f:link.page pageUid="319" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa fa-sign-in"></i> Log in</f:link.page>
  </f:else>
</f:if>
```

This works OK but I have problems with caching. Sometimes the mini-navbar is shown for *an other user*.

My question is: **How can I prevent the partial from caching?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching in Partials can be tricky sometimes..

Take a look at the security viewhelper within the VHS viewhelper collection. It has some nice functionality which covers your case:

```
<v:security.allow anyFrontendUser="TRUE">
    <f:then><!-- protected information displayed --></f:then>
    <f:else><!-- link to login form displayed --></f:else>
</v:security.allow>
```

See the [documenation](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Security/AllowViewHelper.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. But I have problems to use it. I've installed the extension __fluidcontent__ via extension manager as described [here](https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/installation/from-ter.html). The then part and the else part get ignored, i.e. are not rendered. Do I have to configure something to use it in a partial?

Comment: Did you register the namespace in the beginning of the template?, e.g. `{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}`

Comment: No, didn't. Thanks. If I put the namespace directive in the template, it get ignored. If I put it at the top of the partial, Typo3 shows me this error: `Could not analyse class:FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers\Security\AllowViewHelper maybe not loaded or no autoloader?`

Comment: According to this german [article](http://t3seo.de/eigene-fluid-viewhelper-schreiben-i/) about developing custom view helpers, I use this namespace `{namespace v=Tx_Vhs_ViewHelpers}` and it works.

Comment: And for other users: The VHS view helpers are only available, if the extension __VHS: Fluid ViewHelpers__ (key: vhs) is installed. It seems, that fluidcontent is unnecessary (I can deactivate it without any problems).